# Do I have to sign in with the same Microsoft ID for Office 365 Home premium?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

Office 365 Home premium gives rights to be installed on 5 different computers. Do I have to sign in with the same Microsoft ID for all 5 computers or can I sign in with my account on my computer and my wife's account on her computer?

Comment: Those rights are connected to your Microsoft Account.  You might be able to authorize and/or link your wife's account.  I would check Microsoft's documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Each account can have up to 5 installed, but you must use the account to register Office 365.  To enable other users to utilize their accounts they need their own subscription, either directly, or by purchasing O365 family subscription.